# $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{2}{x+y}$ solution by an "integrating term"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I though about this trick and then found an example to apply it to:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{2}{x+y}$$
This is the trick: add  $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$ to both parts
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{dx}{dx}=1+\frac{2}{x+y}+1$$
Using the linearity of $d$
$$\frac{d(x+y)}{dx}=2\frac{1+(x+y)}{x+y}$$
$$\frac{(x+y)d(x+y)}{1+(x+y)}=2dx$$
$$d(x+y)-\frac{d(x+y)}{1+(x+y)}=2dx$$
$$-\frac{d(x+y)}{1+(x+y)}=2dx-d(x+y)$$
Now $2dx-d(x+y)=2dx-dx-dy=dx-dy=d(x-y)$
$$-\frac{d(x+y)}{1+(x+y)}=d(x-y)$$
$$\frac{d(1+x+y)}{1+(x+y)}=d(y-x)$$
Integrating:
$$\ln|1+x+y|=(y-x)+\ln C$$
$$1+x+y=C\exp\left(y-x\right)$$
Is this a one-off case, or a particular example of a certain method? Does anyone know more examples of ODE's that can be solved similarly? I know the [integrating multiplier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147792/solving-ode-with-substitution/147846#147846) theory quite well, but this one seems like something extra to that.

Comment: I can't tell what happened when you went from dx to d(y-x).

Comment: I'll insert the missing steps

Comment: You are making a change of variables.  Your new variable is $x+y$ rather than the original $y$.  This substitution is suggested by the form of the right-hand side.

Comment: It's a nice idea, and aas you can see will work for quite a few variants. Your calculation was more messy than necessary.  Let $u=x+y$. Then your first  line can be rewritten as $\frac{du}{dx}= 2+\frac{2}{u}$. This is a *separable* DE, solve for $u$.  This would have made the later calculations shorter and more transparent.

Comment: yes, I guess in the end it al boils down to changing the variable, though this "method" is meant suggest the change, or make it obvious. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general for equations of the form $y'(x)=f(ax+by+c)$, (where $a, b$ and $c$ are constantes $b\neq 0$), you can use the change of variables $u=ax+by+c$. You obtain the equation:
$$
y'=\frac{u'-a}{b}=f(u)
$$
which can be solved using separation of variables:
$$
\frac{du}{b \,f(u)+a}=dx
$$