# Differential equations: $f(x,y) dx + g(x,y) dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(2xy + 3y^2)dx + (x^2 + 6xy - 2y)dy = 0$$
    $$y(1)  = -1/2$$

How do you solve this? I have just started learning Differential equations and I have some trouble.

Is this equivalent with this?

> $$2y + (6x - 2) = 0$$
>      $$y(1) = -1/2$$

Comment: See [exact equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation).

Comment: Notice that $(2xy+3y^2)dx+(x^2+6xy-2y)dy$ is the divergent of $F(x,y)=x^2y+3xy^2-y^2+c$, c is a constant.

Comment: @GustavoMarra I think you mean it is $d{\bf r} \bullet \nabla F$.

Comment: ooops, that is correct, sorry!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215324/proof-for-exact-differential-equations-shortcut/215346#215346).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation as
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy = 0,
$$
where $df$ is the total differential of a function $f\left(x,y\right)$ that you should determine. Then $df = 0$ implies $f\left(x,y\right)$ is a constant. Determine this constant with the condition on $y\left(1\right)$.