# Exact differential equations. Test to tel if its exact not valid, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got this differential equation:

$$(y^{3} + \cos t)'y = 2 + y \sin t,\text{ where }y(0) = -1$$

Tried to check for $dM/dY = dH/dY$ but I cant seem to get them alike. So what would the next step be to solve this problem?

Comment: On the left hand side of your equation, is it $ (y^3 + \cos t)'y $ or $ (y^3 + \cos t) y' $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really
$$\left(y(t)^{3}+\cos(t)\right)y'(t)=2+y(t)\sin(t)$$ I do not see, why the ode should not be exact.
Let $M(y,t):=-2-y\sin(t)$ and $H(y,t):=y^3+\cos(t)$, the condition for exactness
$$\frac{dM(y,t)}{dy}=\frac{dH(y,t)}{dt}$$ does not fail...

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215324/proof-for-exact-differential-equations-shortcut). Here is how to start. Write the ode as

$$ (y^3 + \cos t)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2 + y \sin t   \implies (y^3 + \cos t){dy} - (2 + y \sin t)dx=0 .$$

Now, you should be able to proceed.