# Under what conditions is the DE exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Under what conditions for $\{a,b,k,l\}$ is $$(ax+by)dx+(kx+ly)dy=0$$ exact? Solve the exact ODE.

A differential equation of the form $I(x,y)dx+J(x,y)dy=0$ is exact if there exists a function $F$ such that $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=I$ and $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=J$.

Here $I=ax+by$ and $J=kx+ly$. Thus, we're looking for a function $F$ such that $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=ax+by$ and $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=kx+ly$. Are those the conditions the question is asking for?

However, after this point things aren't working out. If we assume there exists a function $F$ whose first partial wrt to x is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=ax+by$, which means that the function can be written as $$F=\frac{1}{2}ax^2+bxy+h(y)$$, where $h(y)$ is some unknown function in y.

Since we know that the partial wrt to y is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=kx+ly$, we have $$F=bx+h'(y)=kx+ly$$ or $$h'(y)=kx+ly-bx$$ $$\Rightarrow h=kxy+\frac{1}{2}ly^2-bxy$$

Thus, we get $$F=\frac{1}{2}ax^2+kxy+\frac{1}{2}ly^2$$

This is wrong, since $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \neq ax+by$.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215324/proof-for-exact-differential-equations-shortcut). Here is how you advance

$$ (ax+by)dx+(kx+ly)dy =0 \implies  M=ax+by,\quad N=kx+ly $$

> $$\implies  M_y=b,\quad N_x=k .$$

Now, the condition for exactness is

> $$ M_y=N_x. $$

I think you can finish it now.

Comment: Ah! How could I be so blind?! Thanks a ton Mhenni!

Comment: @Lefty: You are welcome.